# Trying do change background color of the hamburger button to other color, and click again it will change it to back to same color as unclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to do mobile responsive design for top navigation button. I have this problem when user click on the hamburger button, the background color will change to orange which has the color code of #e2ae15 to any color for example red.

When user clicks again it will change back to the default color which is the color code of #e2ae15.

May I know what should I do to make it change color. I tried many ways for example using css called active and focused , but none make it desirably result. One of the best example I could find is this website: https://sutd.edu.sg/ but must be in mobile mode

My Codes:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMwJYv

HTML:

```
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Static navbar -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" id"a">
          <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  //background: transparent !important;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #e2ae15 !important;
  cursor:pointer


  /*&:hover {
    //background: transparent !important;
    background: #e2ae15 !important;
  }*/


  .icon-bar {
    width: 22px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .top-bar {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 10%;
  }
  .middle-bar {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 90%;
  }

  &.collapsed {
    .top-bar {
      transform: rotate(0);      
    }
    .middle-bar {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .bottom-bar {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
  }
}


.red{
  background-color:red;
 }
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Add a class(named **my-class**) to the `nav` tag so that u dont need important. then use that class to target the button.
Add this to your css

```
.my-class.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
.my-class.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover
{
   background-color: red;
}

.my-class .navbar-toggle.collapsed,
.my-class .navbar-toggle.collapsed:hover{
   background-color: orange;
}
```

this will override the default styling of bootstrap. 
When the drawer is open, the `collapsed` class is removed,then  u can target the **navbar-toggle** class.

Updated codepen [link](https://codepen.io/gautamnaik1994/pen/pLXyeK?editors=1100)